# How to join two tables with sum of one column and with condition

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have two tables:

```
table 1
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| id_product  | id_customer  |start_date       |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
|  1          |    1         | 2021-08-28T10:37|
|  1          |    2         | 2021-08-28T11:17|
|  1          |    3         | 2021-08-28T12:27|
|  2          |    1         | 2021-08-28T17:00|  

table 2
  +-------------+------------------+----------+-------------------------------+
| id_customer | stop_date        | duration | 20 other columns like duration|
+-------------+------------------+----------+-------------------------------+
|    1        |  2021-08-27T17:00|    20    | ...
|    1        |  2021-08-26T17:00|    40    | ...
|    2        |  2021-08-29T17:00|    120   | ...
|    1        |  2021-08-30T17:00|    40    | ...
| ..........................................|
```

`start_date` in table 1 is the date the customer started the product.
`stop_date`in table 2 is the date the customer stopped the product.

I want to join these two tables to have something like : one row with :

- productid
- customer_id
- start_date
- sum of all duration for all the stop_date BEFORE start_date.
- same as duration for all the 20 reminding columns.

example for product_id = 1, custom_id = 1 :

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
| id_product  | id_customer  |start_date       | sum(duration) | sum(all other columns from table 2) 
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------------------+
|  1          |    1         | 2021-08-28T10:37|     60
```

I have a really big tables, I am using pyspark with SQL. Do you know an optimised way to this ?

Thank you

EDIT :

There is also an id_product in table2

Comment: is there a `id_product` column in table2?

Comment: yes sorry ! I forget to add it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Table_1.id_product,
    Table_1.id_customer, 
    Table_1.start_date, 
    SUM(duration) AS [sum(duration)]
    ---,SUM(duration2)
    ---,SUM(duration3)
FROM Table_1 
LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON 
    Table_2.id_customer = Table_1.id_customer
    AND Table_2.id_product = Table_1.id_product
    AND Table_2.stop_date < Table_1.start_date
GROUP BY Table_1.id_product,Table_1.id_customer, Table_1.start_date
```

Comment: thanks ! it's perfect and I can understand the logic now. I will take that as an example for all my other query now. thanks again.

Comment: I am curious, If I din't have the product_id in table2, will it be the same without this line AND Table_2.id_product = Table_1.id_product ? @Bijan

Comment: you're welcome.
If product_id is not present in Table_2, the row count of result will not change, but the value of the summary columns will be the same for all product_Id in each Customer_Id of Table_1.